# Control USB Relay in Node JS Program

Tags: node.js, usb

I recently purchased [this USB relay device](http://www.dx.com/p/usb-control-switch-2-channel-5v-relay-module-red-289998?tc=USD&gclid=CKOxvM7eldQCFRY9gQodgIsGuA#.WS4zSOvyvCZ) and would like to control it (open and close each relay with code) in a Node.js program. The product comes with [software](http://m5.img.dxcdn.com/CDDriver/CD/sku.289998.rar) that I believe allows one to do such via c++, an example program that allows you to control the device, and many other files(.cpp, .h, .dll etc.).

How can I use this to control the device in a Node.js program?

Comment: It is stated that the .exe application provided with this device *«Supports Win7, XP 32 system»*.

Comment: The downloadable software is compatible with Win7 and Xp 32 systems but does not include any .exe files. It contains many c++ files (.cpp and .h) and some library files which I believe are important. But this is where my issue lies: I don't know how to utilize any of this in Node.js

Comment: Please at least read about what you buy. [**This link**](http://m5.img.dxcdn.com/CDDriver/CD/sku.289998.rar) is in the web page of your product, under **Overview > Specification > Download link**. and contains the `.exe` files.

Comment: I know, that is what I downloaded and when I extracted the contents of the .rar file it contained many c++ files (.cpp, .h, and .dll) which I don't know how to utilize in Node.js. Actually looking deeper there are a couple .exe files (in the TestApp folder), and I apologize, one of which allows me to control the device but I would like to achieve this with Node.js.

Comment: Look in `USBRelay外部使用开发库/TestApp/` I see `GuiApp_English.exe` there.

Comment: That is the .exe file I was talking about, although it may allow me to control the device's relays, I would like to be able to control the device in a Node.js program.

Comment: Great. So edit your question. Rephrase in order to tell exactly this. And post the .exe content. ;)